# Can't install Devstack for ML2 Mechanism Driver Development

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

I want to develop a Neutron ML2 mechanism driver. The reason is because I want that my own implementation of a software L2 Switch and my own Network Management Agent is able to interact with OpenStack. I have never worked with OpenStack before, but as I have been reading out there, the first thing I have to do is to install Devstack on a VM in order to be able to test the driver. However, I am really struggling on getting Devstack installed on the VM. The installer is always complaining about broken/incompatible dependencies, and when I try to fix them, it just takes forever to install.

Following the [official documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/) does not work for me, it always complains about broken dependencies.

Perhaps someone can point me to an exact distribution/OS version and an OpenStack version that will work for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to install devstack in a clean ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM. What was wrong probably was that I was cloning the latest `master` branch which it seems to be not stable. Note that in the [devstack webpage](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/) it says the following: This release is under development. The current supported release is Xena. So the steps I did to install a working devstack are the following:

1. Add a user `stack` for convenience:

   ```
   $ sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -d /opt/stack -m stack
   $ echo "stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/stack
   $ sudo -u stack -i
   ```
2. `git clone https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack.git`
3. `git chekout stable/xena`
4. Place a `local.conf` file.
   Minimal `local.conf` that worked for me:

   ```
   [[local|localrc]]
   ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
   DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
   RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
   SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

   HOST_IP=10.0.2.18
   ```
5. Install: `./stack.sh`
   Note that the installation will take a while.

Source: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed and ran devstack successfully on Ubuntu 20.04. I also followed the devstack guide you recommended. The only additional steps I did before starting was to first `apt update` and then install `git`.

I usually have to set `HOST_IP` in `local.conf` to my servers ip address as well.

This is where you can download Ubuntu 20.04: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/